# Froala editor is not showing correct linkEditButtons

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I am trying to insert multiple files in Froala editor.
Each File has to show different linkEditButtons based on some conditions.

LinkEditButtons are not shown correctly. The alerts below shows correct buttons . But editor is not getting updated.

How should I get the updated editor instance .

```
$("#froala").on("froalaEditor.file.inserted", function (e, editor, files) {
var editor= $('#froala').data('froala.editor');
var url = editor.link.get();                                                                                                                                     alert("editor.opts.linkEditButtons" + editor.opts.linkEditButtons);
var base = 'pdf;base64';
if (files[0].href.indexOf(base) !== -1) {                                                                        
 editor.opts.linkEditButtons = ['linkRemove'];                                                                        
 alert("editor.opts.linkEditButtons" + editor.opts.linkEditButtons);
} else {                                                                        
editor.opts.linkEditButtons = ['linkOpen', 'linkRemove'];
 alert("editor.opts.linkEditButtons" + editor.opts.linkEditButtons);
}
```